# parse reset password hyper link issue

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, reset-password

I had implemented Parse Server(use parse-server-example) reset password via mailgun-adapter, the config like below:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  ....
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60,
  preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false,
  publicServerURL: 'http://my.domain.com',
  appName: 'MyApp',
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-mailgun-adapter-template',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'no-reply@mydomain.com',
      domain: 'domain.mailgun',
      apiKey: 'key-FromMailGun'
    }
  },
....
});
```

After send reset password via my App, I will receive the mail like:

Hi,

You requested a password reset for MyApp.

Click here to reset it:
http://my.domain.com/apps/appid/request_password_reset?token=tokenid&username=username

But, I click the link that attached in mail. the web display 
Cannot GET /apps/appid/request_password_reset?token=token&username=username.
Therefore, I have to implement my app.get(/request_password_reset) function by myself? or can use Parse Server default html and forms?

Comment: I've experienced a similar problem. A solution would be nice.

Comment: could you try this module instead? `module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter'`

Comment: Also, you do not need to create a function. It is handled by parse already.

Comment: @Lyon so how to fix my issue?

Comment: @章恩齊 have you tried using the module stated in the previous comment? i am using that module and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lyon yes, I had updated module to "parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter". I can receive the reset password mail, but hyper link still get "Cannot GET /apps/appid/request_password_reset?token=token&username=username"

Comment: @章恩齊 Can you try adding this part into your app.('/') ? ' `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');` if it doesnt work, could you upload your whole index.js to let me take a look?

Comment: I can't find how to upload the file. Or you can check below link https://github.com/AnChiChang/ParseMailSetting/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read through your index.js and i think the issue is being your publicServerURL. Make sure you are using the same URL as your serverURL.

http://192.168.200.45:1111/parse

Comment: For me the issue was that in publicServerURL you need to include the "/parse" part